# Making an asynchronous communication database/web-app

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, data-synchronization

Is it possible to make an asynchronous communication with SQL Server 2008 from my ASP.NET MVC 4 web-app ? For example, if a table (Notification) has been updated, I want to see the update from the page which I have already loaded (which contains a dropdown located in a nav-bar in which are placed these notifications) without making a refresh.

What's the best way to do this? And, how, please ?

Comment: SignalR is pretty awesome, check that out for web sockets. Combine that with a data-binding front-end and it's pretty nice.

Comment: WebSockets (as mentioned) is prefered. If you don't want to use that you can do AJAX polling.